# Is there some tutorials bootstrap4xpages?

Tags: xpages, lotus, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm a beginner in developing xpages, I want to use bootsrap4 xpages I ask if there are good tutorials to help me. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't the place to ask for general help like this. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info about SO. Otherwise Google is your best friend here

Answer (score 3):

To use Twitter bootstrap in XPages you need 3 pieces:

- Understand Bootstrap
- The latest Extension library (it includes Bootstrap)
- Head for http://xpages.tv - you will find tutorials there

In a nutshell: add the Extension Library X to your app, go to the app properties and pick the bootstrap theme. Then use the app layout control -> Done.

Make sure to read the install instructions for the extension library (it has 2 steps for Domino Designer).

Good luck

Comment: thanks stwissel,I installeled Extension library in the domino server and designer,then I search tutorials to understand how to develop xpages with bootstrap.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer